# Change the direction flow of CSS columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

So I have CSS like this:

```
#blogPosts{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

and this creates 3 columns perfectly but when I gain another row the order seems to come out vertically like:

```
1,3,5
2,4,6
```

Instead of what I am wanting as:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

---

## Important!

Another important attribute I need, is that there must be a set margin between every post vertically. So for example if you look at the table above if `2` is longer than `1`, the top of `4` will start `y` bellow 1 rather than: the `height of 2` + `y`.

---

The HTML is like this:

```
<div id="blogPosts">
    <div class="blog">Content</div>
    <div class="blog">Content</div>
    ...
</div>
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

I am happy for any solutions, even one that includes javascript/jquery

---

[This](http://galleria.io/themes/folio/) is the kind of thing I am after

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The closest thing would be to use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

```
#blogPosts {
   display: flex;
   align-items: left;
   justify-content: left;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   align-content: flex-end;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/o59gc4hw/2/**

Comment: And even you can change the order as well of items.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Not in Safari or IE < 11, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: @Maximilian looks good on safari http://s16.postimg.org/flntqu7jp/Screen_Shot_2015_05_15_at_10_04_38_AM.png

Comment: @Maximilian for safari you have to use `display:box` if you are using older version

Comment: @Maximilian IE 9 http://s12.postimg.org/ur5m43fbx/Screen_Shot_2015_05_15_at_10_04_38_AM.png

Comment: @Moogs Does that work if the images are all different heights like in the image attached to the OPs question? http://jsfiddle.net/goldengonaz/7637hag3/6/

Comment: 6 years now, anyone found a solution which would essentially solve masonry layout with pure CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Well on the first sight I thought you should look at the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library. When you then search for masonry, you possibly also will find [masonry flexible box](http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox) and [masonry columns](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/).

Problem with both the columns and flexible box solutions is that the first items are in the first column.

I found one possible solution, which only works when your number of item is fixed.

For nine items in three columns:

```css
#blogPosts {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.blog {
  color: white;
  width: 33%;
}
.blog:nth-child(3n+1) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -webkit-order: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: 0;
          order: 0;
}
.blog:nth-child(3n+2) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}
.blog:nth-child(3n+3) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
}
.blog:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9) {
  page-break-after: always;
  -webkit-break-after: always;
     -moz-break-after: always;
          break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div id="blogPosts">
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:blue; height:50px;">1</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:red; height:75px;">2</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:green; height:100px;">3</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:black; height:30px;">4</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:yellow; height:50px;">5</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:purple; height:80px;">6</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:pink; height:150px;">7</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:orange; height:15px;">8</div>
    <div class="blog" style="background-color:gold; height:50px;">9</div>
</div>
```

The above use the flexible box, with the `order` property and `nth` child selectors. And finally also see: [How to specify an element after which to wrap in css flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flex)

Comment: This would seem like a great answer, but it doesn't seem to work on Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your misunderstanding how the column separation works with css colunms. Your blogPosts class is separating the content as evenly as possible across 3 colunms so it appears like:

> 1 3 5
>   2 4 6

but if you do

```
<div class="blogPosts">
    Content 1
</div>
<br>
<div class="blogPosts">
    Content 2
</div>
<br>
<div class="blogPosts">
     Content 3
</div>
```

Then the conents would appear as:

> 1
>  
>   2
>  
>   3

but the content within these sections would fit to the 3 colunms.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
#flex-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 251);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  column-gap: 30px;
  }
#flex-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_column-gap_grid

Answer (score -2):

This can be implemented with simple css.
HTML:

```
<div id="blogPosts">
<div class="blog">1Content</div>
<div class="blog">1Content</div>
<div class="blog">2Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS: make the "blog" class as inline-block and float to left as show below.

```
.blog {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 33.3%;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: -999em;
     padding-bottom: 999em; 
}

#blogPosts{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is will fix the height issue that you had as well. :)

Comment: i don't think this solves the height problem, see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXWRrq

Comment: @BassJobsen, Sorry, My bad I misunderstood the question. What I thought was the second row elements should start from same position. Please find the updated answer above. [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/prashanth_j05/xbxuryhL/1/)

Comment: well nice done. But i still think it does not solves: "at the table above if 2 is longer than 1, the top of 4 will start next to 2 rather than below"