# Control the number of items on each flex-line when container is set to wrap

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I am using css flexbox to distribute a number of items in a container. I have a flex container like this:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;            
    align-content : center;
    justify-content : center;
    align-items : center;
}
```

When I add a certain number of fixed width/height items to the container they are placed as expected: if they don´t fit on a single flex-line the container creates a new one and some of the items are wrapped onto the next line. What I would like to do is have some control over the number of items that are displaced to the next line at he same time.

For example, if I place 9 items (that at first fit on one flex-line) and then I shrink the browser window, the container will first displace only the rightmost item to the next line, leaving 8 items on the first flex-line and only one on the second, what is not very aesthetically pleasant in my opinion. If I shrink the window more, I have a 7-2 distribution, and so on.

My question is, is there any way I can control how many items are displaced at once? My intent would be to have the number of items evenly distributed among the flex-lines, having the wider ones always on top, for any number of items.

For example, 9 items would be distributed this way:

- When all items fit in a line:
  1 flex-line: 9 items
- When 9 items don´t fit jump to:
  2 flex-lines: 5 items on the first line, 4 on the second.
- When 5 items don´t fit in a line jump to:
  3 flex-lines: 3-3-3
- When 3 items don´t fit in a line jump to:
  5 flex-lines: 2-2-2-2-1

Is there any way (maybe with the aid of jquery) to accomplish something like that? Any solution for a known number of elements would be appreciated, although my intent is to find one dynamically applicable to any number of items.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is sometimes referred to as ***Quantity Queries***.

If *media queries* allow for breakpoints based on viewport dimensions, *quantity queries* allow for breakpoints based on content quantity (e.g., sibling count).

It's not part of any official standard but I wouldn't call it a hack. The code can be quite elegant. It is a bit involved, however. Here you go:

- [Quantity Queries for CSS](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css)
- [Styling elements based on sibling count](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)
- [How to specify an element after which to wrap in css flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19574851/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `flex-basis`?

```
.container .item {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

It will divide to maximum 4 item per row.