# Make wrapped flexbox's children squeeze into parent's height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build a grid that dynamically makes space for new cells and eventually wraps around. I think some pictures will best illustrate what I'm trying to do.

*The black box is the viewport, the light blue boxes are the elements that are added.*

One box just fills the whole viewport:
[image: 1x1 grid]

As more boxes are added, the layout squeezes them in horizontally:
[image: 1x3 grid]

Until a minimum width is reached and the layout wraps around:
[image: 2x3 grid]

What's the best way to do this? I tried with flexbox, but didn't manage to squeeze the boxes into the viewport vertically when `flex-wrap` was enabled - they would just overflow.

EDIT: Added snippet showing what I've tried:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 210px;
  width: 330px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

main > div {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}

main > div > p {
  /* Content placeholder */
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
This looks relatively good (except for the width of the 4th div):
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>

As soon as you add content, it breaks:
<main>
  <div><p></p></div>
  <div><p></p></div>
  <div><p></p></div>
  <div><p></p></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Look into `min-height` property in flex items.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Michael_B I just added a snippet.

Comment: @Ricky `min-height` was mentioned on a few websites where I did research, but I'm not sure how I would apply it. Setting `min-height` to any possible value on the `div`s doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see simple way to set breakpoint without knowing what amount of elements it will contain, but usage of flex-basis may help you, also I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox) case which may be your solution.