# Responsive flexbox layout: reordering elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a responsive layout as outlined in the image, left side would be mobile, right side desktop. This would be relatively easy using flexbox if I could set a fixed height for the wrapper, but because the content is dynamic this is not possible.

[image: Layout]

Another solution would be to use position absolute on element C, but this seems very hacky, I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Here is a framework for the code:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.section-a {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .section-a {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}

.section-b {
  background: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .section-b {
    flex-basis: 66%;
  }
}

.section-c {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .section-c {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section-a">A</div>
  <div class="section section-b">B</div>
  <div class="section section-c">C</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd be using CSS-Grid for this... I'm sure that this has been covered before...I'll see if I can find a duplicate.

Comment: @syberen check my updated answer

Comment: I don't think this is possible with flex using your layout without adding a some sort of height restriction to the wrapper but perhaps this may give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox

Comment: Even though the content is dynamic, what's stopping you from using the `overflow-y: auto` or just `overflow: auto`? Personally I'd still go with the Flexbox.

Comment: Interesting idea, didn't consider that. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using `grid`. I have simplified your code and removed unwanted `css`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [row1-start] auto [row2-start] auto [row2-end];
}

.section {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.section-a {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}  
.section-b {
  grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.section-c {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section-a">A</div>
  <div class="section section-b">B</div>
  <div class="section section-c">C</div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2osauxq/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this method. I've been apprehensive to use CSS grid so far because of browser support.

Comment: @syberen if this solved your question, please mark this answer as "accepted". it will motivate us to contribute more towards the community.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit:** it's an attempt, as I misunderstood OP's question. My answer has a given `.wrapper` `height`.

A solution using **flex** with the following properties:

- [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/order)
- [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

This code applies for your desktop layout:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.section {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-a {
    height: 25vh; // for example
}

.section-b {
    order: 3;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.section-c {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section section-a">A</div>
    <div class="section section-b">B</div>
    <div class="section section-c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is wanting a dynamic height based on a and c - this is fixed to 100vh. **From question:** *This would be relatively easy using flexbox if I could set a fixed height for the wrapper, but because the content is dynamic this is not possible.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time nevertheless!