# How to wrap after nth element in flexbox column layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, drupal

I have been through a lot of posts on SO like [How to specify an element after which to wrap in css flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox)  but all of them talk about row based layout. I have a fixed html being generate by a drupal. The task is to force any `li` after 3rd `li` into second column and keep height auto:

```css
ul {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>Unlimited</li>
</ul>
```

So the first column needs to have fixed thee elements and all other elements should be pushed to the second column. Please note that the `ul` can't have fixed height, and the html structure can be changed only a little bit with twig in drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't set fixed heights, flex won't work.

You need a height limit on the container to trigger a wrap.

However, the layout is pretty simple with Grid:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px; /* width of grid columns */  
  grid-auto-flow: column;  /* directional flow of the items */
  width: 250px;
  background: gray;
}

li:nth-child(n + 4) {
  grid-column: 2; /* every item after the 3rd goes to column 2 */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>Unlimited</li>
</ul>
```