# Bootstrap wrap list element into 3 row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like to wrap a list elements into 3 column using one `<ul>`

Just to clarify what I want:

[image: SS]

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush row-cols-3">
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using `row-cols-3` but it does not working.

This is how it looks right now:
[image: SS]

**UPDATE**

#1

[image: SS]

#2

[image: SS]

#3

[image: SS]

Comment: You want the list to have three rows? Does the fourth row start a new column, or just disappear?

Comment: I want, the first to be at (1;1), the second be at (1;2), the third be at (1;3), the fourth be at (2;1), fifth be at (2;2), where (row; column)

Comment: Almost, good but there is some problem with the lines, I added a UPDATE picture to my code.

Comment: with the newer one, this is even worser, each li is in the same row, UPDATE pic #2

Comment: try giving `row` class to `ul` and `col-4` class to each `li`

Comment: @burkay that is still not good UDAPTE #3

Comment: Ok, found another solution. Will post it in an answer shortly.

Comment: @burkay I have just posted the correct soltution, but if you have a better one show me

Comment: Just posted it. Seen your version as well. Looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution thanks to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/list-group/#horizontal and @fabio.sang's comment at [How to specify an element after which to wrap in css flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox#comment67567427_30054940) . Added some more `li` items for testing purposes.

```css
li {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal flex-wrap">
  <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that CSS is not necessary , bootstrap has those classes

Comment: right, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This way the border and the rows and columns will be perfect.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal row">
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-group-item col-4 border-0 border-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```